# Views causing Storyboard Issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Using views within my application is causing my storyboard to do strange things. This is making it very difficult for me to make changes. I thought the issue was due to the fact that using a view limits the size of your next view and so on.

However, it's now causing issues where I have to move tableviews into strange places to make them display correctly on the device.

[image]

These views both display correctly on my device. However the view at the top is only half the screen. There is also a navigation bar throughout the app which can no longer be seen on my storyboard.

The first view was fine until earlier today when it randomly began displaying as seen below.

Has anyone had this issue before and know how to fix it?

Comment: Its moves to where I move it. Nothing else changes though.

Comment: Any constraints warnings?

Comment: None whatsoever which is strange.

Comment: Do you have a sample project I can try?